# How to automatic set nil when release a object

Tags: objective-c

With my knowledge set `nil` to a variable when `release` it is always a good idea or make no difference. But it is never a bad idea.

So, to set nil to a object we have to do:

```
[object release];
object=nil;
```

But this is 2 lines. I always have to remember to do it. So, there are a automatic way to set nil when release a object?

One simple idea is:

```
#define release(VAR) [VAR release]; VAR=nil;
release(object);
```

But with this I will have to change the codes in all files and isn't a good idea change the code in this way because it isn't a "natural" way of objective-c. Anyone know another trick?

Comment: so you want to make the code better without changing anything?

Comment: It almost this. I only don't want to forget set nil. And use `release(object)` isn't a "natural" way :)

Comment: you can always analyze your code for this, and for the ones the analyzer doesn't find, you can profile memory leaks. it will find all problems except retain loops.

Comment: You should have a look at Mike Ash's ["Zeroing Weak References"](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html) You're dealing with strong references, of course, but you might find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object is a **retained property**:

**.h**

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSObject *object
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize object;
```

All you need to do is call:

```
self.object = nil;
```

Indeed, the generated setter takes care of doing the release for you, so that one line above is equivalent to writing

```
[object release];
object=nil;
```

Comment: This will also work naturally with Automatic Reference Counting.

Comment: @Mutix  I do not know this. Lol, if I see this before, I will think is a memory leak. It NEED to be a `self.object = nil`?? Only `object = nil` will cause a memory leak? Obvious `otherObject.object = nil` will work too, right?

Answer (score 2):

I reckon you're best off just writing both the lines throughout, as is normal. Then at least your code will make sense to anyone else who has to maintain it later down the line.

Answer (score 2):

You almost never need to do this. If you have this throughout your code anywhere but dealloc you are not using accessor methods correctly.

if you do this,

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [foo release];
  foo = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

What does the `foo = nil;` line get you? The only thing i can think of is that it might hide a bug you would otherwise have found earlier.

So, no, i would not say that it is never a bad thing.

Comment: What is the problem? Let's say `foo` is a class variable. If you release it and another variable access this memory, it crash the program. If this variable access nil, it not crash and continue. If you need that value, well, is better continue than crash (even if will crash a fell life before)

Comment: If you are trying to access foo after you have released it you have a bug that should be fixed, not ignored.